# How to read data from tcp socket in Android

Tags: android, tcpsocket

Before, I sent som data (ex: AC current, AC voltage, DC current, DC voltage, etc..) by module Adruino Mega 2560 + ESP 8266. This data was saved in server. Then I want to Android App read this data via TCP Socket. Would you mind helping me ?

Comment: Replace ( write, read. replaceall).

Comment: @blackapps what do you mean ?

Comment: I wonder why you can write to a socket but are unable to read from it. The function names are about the same. Only replace write by read was the message. Also replace output by input.

Comment: I made 1 class to connect socket .  When I push button "Refesh", it 'll send request to server. I need what in server to return to app. I changed but it not working

Comment: `I need what in server to return to app. I changed ` ??? Can you rephrase that? I have no idea where you are talking about.

Comment: `Before, I sent som data ` Who sent that? To whom? The Ardino to the ESP? Android to the ESP? It is all so unclear.

Comment: Is your situation like this: "I have an ESP8266 and there is some data on it. Now i want to make an Android app that grabs that data from the ESP" ? If so then you must install a server on the esp to begin with. Now did you?

Comment: vy-huỳnh, I suggest you review a few top rated questions and then, as blackapps stated, edit your post to make it more clear what your problem is. However, I do believe that I understand your question; there are a number of ways to connect to a server, one of the easiest is HTTP (which I assume you mean). Have a look at Volley for example, https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.